# 2 side by side divs centered?

Tags: html, css

Well i have 2 divs that i want to be side by side and aligned in the center of the page?

HTML:

```
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#box
{
width: 450px;
color: #ffffff;
height: 500px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
background-color:#666;
border-radius:15px;
float:left;
margin-right:15px;}
```

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

(I cant post photo's because i dont have 10 rep sorry!) but i want them to be under and aligned to the nav bar. Thank you.

Comment: Side note: IDs has to be unique. Use classes instead

Comment: If you could put up a fiddle, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wrapper around those div like

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Then with css

```
#wrapper {
     text-align: center;
     width: ??; //add yours
     height: ??; //add yours
}
```

**FYI:**  `id` should be unique

Updates:

```
.box {
    width: 450px;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    background-color:#666;
    border-radius:15px;    
}

#wrapper{
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/8YxnR/6/)

Comment: @KeillenHayes try `margin: auto` instead of `text-align:center`

Comment: To be correct, `.box` should be `display: inline-block` and you won't have to define width and height for `#wrapper` http://jsfiddle.net/CXPD3/

Comment: @Naele thanks, I missed to add in answer, Now I have updated.

Answer (score 2):

What you need here is use `inline-block` instead of `float` that allows you to use the `text-align` property on the parent. Try this:

```
.box {
  /*float:left; Remove this*/
  display:inline-block; /*Add this*/
}
```

<sub>Since ID must be unique I use `.box` add that class on the divs</sub>

And on the parent use:

```
body {
  text-align:center;
}
```

<sub>I use body in this case I don't see any other parent but change it for the real one</sub>

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/WJfx5/

*Also you can read **[This Article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)** to know about the use of `inline-block` elements*

Answer (score 1):

put this 2 divs in another big div, and add margin: 0 auto; to it and a width.

```
<div class="bigdiv">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

.bigdiv { margin:0 auto; width: 930px }
.box:last-child {margin-right: 0px;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You have just stopped me from pulling my hair out over this man!